# Перевод переписки из WhatsUp

Tags: sms

Есть ли сайт или готовая программа для того, чтобы перевести смс-переписку с WhatsUp? У меня есть уже готовая закодированная переписка, просто я не могу перевести её.

Comment: @ziyad при отсутствии кириллической клавиатуры, [translit.net](http://translit.net/) вам в помощь.

Comment: @ziyad, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести, какие технологии вы используете и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Translate.google.com и для замены его API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api